# Team Foundation error, Host Id

Tags: sharepoint, tfs

I just moved my tfs 2013 in one server to tfs 2015 update 1 on another server, and I also changed the DB server behind.

Everything worked perfectly fine on the migration except for the sharepoint integration, unfortunately during the migration, the sharepoint content database where it was pointing to had physical errors on its content database (wss_content).

However I created another webapplication http://portaltfs, where I want to make the integration with tfs.

However, when I click on change or add, I get this error

[image]

Comment: Is there more error message in Event log? Could you describe the environment of the old TFS and new TFS, like OS version, SQL version, sharepoint version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2015/09/30/migration-update-from-team-foundation-server-tfs-2013-to-tfs-2015-with-reporting-and-sharepoint/) to see whether your upgrade process is correct. And try try to remove SharePoint extension and re-configure it.

Also, since you would attach the content database which migrated from TFS 2013, after creating new web application with the web site name and port number, go to 
Manage Content Database from Central Administrator site, and select the web application created and check Remove content database. Then open SharePoint 2013 Management shell and use Mount-SPContentDatabase to attach the old content database. Refer to the blog for more details.